# In BUILDER: how access outer loop variable

Tags: psychopy

In PsychoPy Builder, I have a nested loop situation.

The inner loop processes a set of stimuli from a column in an excel file [ the Image component has the Image attribute set to $file1 - file1 being the column header ]

Once its finished, the out loops takes it back and does some stuff before kicking off the inner loop again.

My problem is that I want to use a different column of data for the inner loop each time I start it. e.g use column 'file2' the second time around, then column file3 ,..

I can't work out how to do this without sticking all the stimulii names into code but that will then be much harder for the researcher to edit it.

Any ideas ?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 2):

This is a common trick. The column name needs to go into a variable in the *outer* loop's condition file, e.g.:

```
innerColumnName
file1
file2
file3
```

Then in the Image component, put:

```
$eval(innerColumnName)
```

This will, for example, evaluate the string "file1" into the variable name file1.

Comment: Excellent, Thanks, and simpler than what I ended up doing:- $(eval('file'+str(trials_2.thisTrialN +1))) which, although it doesn't need an extra column, it is less clear to pass onto a non-programmer to work with.